# Know position "person" in file with ftell() and fseek() in c

Tags: c, data-structures, file-handling

I have a file that containes informations about workers:

> First name | Last name | phone (empty space)  First name 2... All in one line

**And the question is to display information of worker when user choose 1,2 or 3... each number indicate a worker.**

And i found this program that does that, but i didn't understand how the code work from **line 30 to line 38** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {


typedef struct personne{
    char nom [20] ;
    char prenom [15] ;
    int age ;
    char tel[12] ;
} personne ;
personne p;

FILE * f ;
if ((f = fopen("Contacts.dat", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf("\nImpossible de lire le fichier commandes.dat\n");
}
else{
    int num ; /* Bloc number to be found */
    long taille, /* File size  */
    pos ; /* position in the file */

    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END) ;
    taille = ftell(f);

    printf (" Enter rank : ") ;
    scanf ("%d",&num) ;
    num--;                   //FROM HERE (LINE 30) !!!
    pos = num * sizeof(personne) ;

    if ( num < 0 || pos >= taille )
        printf ("-- This rank does not exist ") ;
    else {
        fseek (f, pos, SEEK_SET) ;
        fread (&p, sizeof(p), 1, f) ; //TO HERE (LINE 38)!!!
        printf ("nom : %s\n", p.nom) ;
        printf ("prenom : %s\n", p.prenom) ;
        printf ("age : %d\n", p.age) ;
        printf ("telephone : %s\n", p.tel) ;
    }

    fclose (f) ;
}}
```

Am knew to c language any help will be appreciated

Comment: `num--; ` is decremented because record `1` is at offset `0` as with array indexing. `pos = num * sizeof(personne);` computes the location in the file of the beginning of the `num`th record. Then the range of `num` is checked for validity, but ideally that should have been checked sooner. Then `fseek (f, pos, SEEK_SET);` moves the file pointer to the desired location. Finally your line 38 reads the file record into a `struct` of the right type, so its members can be printed. Or so I presume, because from your line number comments, there is one line missing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much, oh it's my fault the line number is 37

Comment: @WeatherVane Shouldn't this be an answer instead of a comment?